# Spring kafka consumer reading less chunk in batchlistener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am building a Spring Kafka Consumer application that consumes messages from a Kafka Topic and performs a database task. The messages are produced in a large batch once every day - so the Topic has about 5 million messages loaded in 30 minutes. The Topic has 3 partitions.

The Spring Kafka Consumer (annotated with @KafkaListener and using a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory) is triggered in very short batches.

The batch size is sometimes just 1 or 2 messages. It would help performance if it can consume about 500 messages at once and process it together (for example, I could update the database in a single update SQL), instead of connecting to the database for each message.

Is there any other configuration I could use to increase the bath size of the consumer so that it can fetch at least 500 records and then call the listener? Below are my configurations. Is there something call min poll records?

spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size=12000 
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-maxt-wait=20000 
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=500 
sping.kafka.listener.type=BATCH 
sping.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=20000

Comment: No; there is no `min.poll.records` just the `fetch-min-size` (which maps to the Kafka `fetch.min.bytes` property) and `fetch-max-wait` (K: `fetch.max.wait.ms`). However, you do have a typo in `fetch-max-wait`. It's not clear why you would get such short batches, given your configuration.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I further increased the fetch-min-size, now it is working for me with the same config.

Comment: Try to set the value of `max.partition.fetch.bytes` to a larger value